# Change the color of a symbol based on a value

Tags: android, listview, imageview

In my Android App I got a Menu, based on a ListView, the code looks something like this:

```
  <RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/androidList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/symbol1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aNametxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/appIconIV"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appIconIV"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Android Name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aVersiontxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/aNametxt"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/aNametxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aNametxt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Android Version"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want this app to have a specific theme for a specific level the user can reach within the app (the levels are based on a score). Let's say we got level 1, level 2... Now I could design 5 different symbols, each with a specific **`color`** and set the specific **`icon`** for the specific level - ***but when I think of the amount of data for 5 x 10 Icons + Backgrounds... I ask myself: is there any way to make this a lot more light weight?***
Or should I go server side with the Icons and load them directly from my server? It should be as secure as possible to prevent users from faking the displayed surface.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both ways, but if keeping light weight in my mind, best option is server side. Load them directly from the server.

You can use a library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) it is a light weight image loading library and also has transformation features.